# iOS: How can you stop live-streaming AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have an AVPlayer for playing live steam.
The audio playing works very well like that.

```
class CustomPlayer: ObservableObject {

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var p: AVPlayer

    init (){
        let string = "https://..."
        let url: URL! = URL(string: string)
        p = AVPlayer(url: URL)
        p.play()
        try! self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        try! self.audioSession.setActive(true)
    }

}
```

But as soon as I come to the point of pausing/stopping it, it becomes difficult.

The method `p.pause()` does work, but pauses the player so that it starts playing at the same point as it was paused. That is not helpful, because it should still play the live stream without delay of course.

So my thought was to only mute the player with `p.isMuted = true`. But then I've got the problem that the wrong playback state is presented in the NowPlayingInfoCenter in the control center because this inherits from the playback state of the AVPlayer. To change the playback state manually my app needs special permission/entitlements. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter/2588243-playbackstate/

So that's why I am stuck with this issue and I hope someone can help me solve it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to simply replace the current AVPlayerItem with the "new" AVPlayerItem with the same URL, i.e. `p.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: string))`. Similarly to stop live streaming I think you can do this: `p.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It isn't very performant, but it works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `p.pause()`, you can try this:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if avPlayer.player?.rate ?? 0 > 0 {
        avPlayer.contentOverlayView?.removeAllSubviews()
    }
}
```

And add the observer beforehand:

```
avPlayer.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Note:
Here, `avPlayer` should be of type `AVPlayerViewController()`